# if two random variables are jointly Gaussian, does that mean they are Gaussian individually? or vice-versa?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am new into the term of jointly Gaussian. I was wondering, suppose X and Y are two random variables having a Gaussian distribution. My question is whether they will be jointly Gaussian?

Or in the opposite sense, if (X,Y) is jointly Gaussian, does that mean X and Y both have Gaussian distribution?

What is the actual relation in these two case? Thank you.

Comment: Please search the site; this question has been asked and answered several times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian then each one of them is Gaussian. The converse is false: Take $Y=X$ when $|X| \leq 1$ and $Y=-X$ when $|X| >1$ where $X$ has standard normal distribution. The joint distribution does not even have  density in this case so it is not Gaussian.

Comment: thanks, simply explains my query :)

Comment: Someone would call your example "degenerate Gaussian". A better example, which would satisfy them too, is $X$ and $XZ$, where $X$ is centered Gaussian, and $Z$ is an independent Rademacher variable ($+1$ or $-1$ with probability $1/2$).

Comment: @zhoraster Thank  you for the comment. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Even better this way ;)